# check server configs with script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write an script to automatically check all of the configuration files and put result in a file,so for the first i have to check apache modules if these(my list)modules installed say ok in report if not say false and with modules name,i did this but ....

```
#!/bin/bash
for LIN in `cat $1`
do
    #if grep LIN "$2"; then
    if [[ $LIN == *$1* ]]; then
        echo T
    else
        echo F
    fi
done
```

I must put this command into my script (apache -M) to list all available modules and put it into a variable.
there is another mention , this script must work on the other servers and machines, i mean it must be portable, it must not works depends on the other input file .

any help please.

thanks all

Comment: `grep -F -q "$2" "$1" && echo T || echo F`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems:

1. Useless use of `cat`
2. Not quoting your variables

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r LIN
do
    #if grep LIN "$2"; then
    if [[ "$LIN" == *"$2"* ]]; then
        echo T
    else
        echo F
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the nswer ,but iam confused a lot .

Comment: look ,i want to check if some modules on servers installed or not.i can list all installed modules with "Apache -M" command,and i have a requirement modules list in a file ,now these file must be compared to each other after converting there lines to string (is it true?).so can you tell what can i do?

Comment: Looks like you are changing the nature of problem using comment. I would suggest you accept this answer since it solves the stated problem and start a new question with the new problem.

Comment: :) , that was a good and smart answer.ok , i'll start a new post.

Comment: but i can see at my first sentence that i was explained what i want.anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: People providing your answer have to go by the script you have posted and will suggest correction/improvement in the code. Also I suggest you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.